# crossed the lower half like a gash of fire

Tags: vocabulary

"Her face was not beautiful. It was long, and palely lighted, while the **mouth crossed the lower half like a gash of fire**. The lips were as voluptuous as before. Her brows were heavy..."

In this scene a woman is being described. Yet, I cannot understand the way her mouth looks: the mouth crossed the lower half like a gash of fire.
gash means wound, a deep cut. But it doesn't make sense here. A gash of fire?  Also, the mouth crossed the lower half of what? Of the face? How did it cross? Can you please explain what you visualize when you read the sentence in bold?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: 'Gash of fire' conjures up the image in Lord of the Rings where, in Khazad-dûm,  the orcs chasing the members of the Fellowship could not attack them because of fire flaming from a long fissure in the floor. Of course, ghâsh meant fire in orcish.  I'd stick to Tolkien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up 'gash' on Google images and you get something like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8Ksd.png

As you can see there is a remarkable similarity to a pair of lips.

I imagine that if someone used a vivid shade of lipstick, their lips could resemble a gash.

'It' refers to 'face' and so, therefore does 'lower-half'.  The verb 'crossed' relates to the following definition.

> Full Definition of CROSS
>
> transitive verb
>
> 1
>
> a :  to lie or be situated across
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cross)

EDITED

See Brian Donovan's comment below. It shows how 'gash of fire' could look like lips.

Maybe lipstick like this would produce the desired effect. https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgtrm.jpg

Comment: But the lips are also said to be voluptuous, which suggests they are not thin. And then there is the "of fire" thing: "gash of fire" suggests to me a volcanic image like [this](http://www.wildjunket.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/tn_IMG_4672.jpg), or (more mouth-like) [this](http://siberiantimes.com/PICTURES/ECOLOGY/TOLBACHIK-APRIL-2013/inside%2013.jpg).

Comment: @BrianDonovan - Good point. I missed 'voluptuous'. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The description of the face is almost of a crude or primitive [mask](https://www.google.com/search?q=primitive%20war%20masks%20red%20lips&num=20&newwindow=1&es_sm=93&tbm=isch&imgil=WCQHwQhfCwFduM%253A%253BfYlPLA9ItxuL9M%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fhdwpics.com%25252Fprimitive-mythology-mask-hdw216725&source=iu&pf=m&fir=WCQHwQhfCwFduM%253A%252CfYlPLA9ItxuL9M%252C_&biw=1374&bih=931&usg=__RB6WcC226W-lNzovKiYgZ0mVgn8%3D&ved=0CEQQyjdqFQoTCKzxp6L64scCFQQcPgodwAUC8g&ei=xHrsVaz_IoS4-AHAi4iQDw#imgrc=zKWuaQiPqLLD8M%3A&usg=__RB6WcC226W-lNzovKiYgZ0mVgn8%3D). "Gash of fire" and "the lower half" are  impressionistic and convey the idea that the features are not delicately formed.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please explain what you visualize

I visualize a white woman with pale skin wearing vividly red lipstick as her only obvious make-up.  The lipstick is more of a blood red than a fire-engine red.  The mouth is more of the Joan Crawford type (wide) than the Clara Bow-Betty Boop mouth (small and pert).